# Question about steps to convert from Ubercart to Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce, ubercart

After running into some discount functionality/module install issues with Ubercart for Drupal 7, my client has agreed to try Drupal Commerce. Do I need to completely remove everything related to Ubercart before Drupal Commerce can work, or can I unpublish the existing Ubercart content and disable the modules to allow my client to give it a test drive?

I see that there are some machine names that are the same from one to the other, which could pose a problem.

Comment: It could be messy if you try and have multiple different types of content (and modules) on one site. I would recommend spinning up another site -- you could clone it and then use that as the starter.

Comment: Have you tried Ubercart Discount Coupons module?

Comment: When the Drupal page for a module starts with, "** Sadly, I no longer have time to give this module the attention it deserves. If anyone is interested in becoming a co-maintainer, please post in the issue queue." and when the last update on the development release is 2012, I don't use the module no matter how attractive it looks. But, I have to admit that the temptation was strong.

Answer (score 0):

The two projects are incompatible because of the lack of name spacing in Drupal 7. Your best bet will be to completely delete all of the Ubercart related content and uninstall all of its modules. For obvious reasons, I'd recommend not doing this on your client's live site. Create a copy from a backup and perform your test / research in that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ryan.  We tried the same thing and NEVER recovered the site.  You might be entering the world of spaghetti.  It was Drupal 6 however.  Whatever your "discount functionality/module install issues" are - would probably be easier to ***work through*** than converting to Drupal Commerce.  ALSO if you take the time to count the modules available or that could be converted and fixed using Coder - AND the number of Drupal core contributors who actually develop for Ubercart also - you might find a stronger case for staying with Ubercart after all

Comment: I actually posted for advise on a different site before choosing Ubercart over Drupal Commerce to start with. The client was already familiar with Ubercart for Drupal 6, so the positive comments and the client experience drove that decision.
I have removed Commerce from the install with Ubercart and will try Commerce in a clone. The site is not "live" yet, which is a benefit.

Comment: It sounds like the client has Drupal 6 running with Ubercart - and you should consider the number of MODULES available for both Drupal 6 and 7 under Ubercart as well as the modules which DO NOT exist under Commerce at all.  It sounds like you should duplicate the D6 - and concentrate on how to UPGRADE it and incorporate the new features they seek.  A lot of Drupal pages have stale information - and if you look at the module ages and see there are 3 maintainers - Discount Coupons is alive and well.  Sadly -YOU will have install both ans use both to compare.  I would stick with what they have

Comment: In this particular case, I did stick with Ubercart and only removed it after not being able to find a solution to the discount install problem. After numerous posts and questions with no answers, I am trying Drupal Commerce in a clone.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer: In the process of deleting Ubercart, I found that Product Classes created in Ubercart, remain in Content Types. Of course, the cart fields are missing, but all the custom fields created for client needs are still available.

Partial question remaining to be answered: can these Content Types be connected to Drupal Commerce as Products?